# Unix parsing pipe delimited format string in ksh

Tags: string, parsing, shell, unix, ksh

I am writing ksh script to parse a pipe delimited string

```
export dummy="abc"  
echo "123|456|789" | awk '{split($0,output,"|"); print output[3] output[2] output[1]}'
```

above code seems to work , but I am not able to assign value of output[3] to dummy.

Is there a way to do such parsing, but I want to assign the parsing result in a variable within ksh space  i.e. dummy (in above sample)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell can do it:

```
line="123|456|789"
IFS='|' read a b c <<END
$line
END
echo $c  # => 789
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign awk variables (i.e. `output[3]`) to shell variables (i.e. `dummy`), you can only assign the output of awk to a variable, e.g.

```
export dummy=`echo "123|456|789" | awk -F'|' '{ print $3; }'`
```

However, awk is a bit overkill here, `cut` will work just as well:

```
export dummy=`echo "123|456|789" | cut -d'|' -f3`
```

Comment: thanks ben23, i wish i can accept two answers for one question